# How do I determine which Mount Point and which Flags to use when creating a Partition?

Tags: linux, partition, software-installation, kali-linux, system-installation

I don't understand why this process is so damn complicated. I used Gparted already to create 2 new partitions on a recently formatted HDD in my Lenovo ideapad 330, in which I selected them both to be primary partitions, (one ntfs and the other gpt/ext4).

Long story short, after rebooting and attempting to load and install the 'Windowsfx' distro I have, it still prompted me to create a new partition again.

I'd like to get the most out of the hard drive in my laptop, by creating 2 partitions if possible, but now that the Linuxfx Installer made me start over, I'm not sure how to create 2 separate partitions at the 'Create a Partition' screen.

In either case, using GPT, I can see that ext4 seems to be a commonly-preferred File System option. As for the so-called [ Mount Point ], I have no idea what to put (keeping in mind, that I still want 2 separate partitions, or at least some type of dual-boot option).

On top of that, there's a fairly sizable list of "Flags" of which I mostly don't understand either. After doing some research, I notice the [ root ] flag and [ swap ] flag appear to be common options to employ, but that still doesn't help me determine which of these I should really choose, or if I can even choose more than one flag (or if it even makes sense to do that).

Bottom line, I just want to be able to install two separate distros (each on it's own partition), putting 'Windowsfx' on one, and 'Kali Linux' on the other, if possible...?

I admit, I've mostly been a Windows user up to this point in time, but ever since Microsoft decided to go super-tyrannical with Win10, by killing probably one of it's most stable, albeit not perfect operating systems it likely has ever created, (Windows 7), that really was the final straw that broke the camel's back for me, not to mention all their BS telemetry and forcing the users hand to upgrade and create a MS account. Screw that and screw MS!

Anyway, I've always maintained my own system, never once, ever relying on Auto-updates from MS to update my desktop Win7, but now that even cyber-security software vendors are parting ways with support for Win7, I realize I have little choice but to find a viable alternative some time soon, if I want to stay connected. Anyway, just thought I'd provide some background on my intentions.

Any suggestions and/or basic guidance on the partition issue I mentioned above, would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to be able to install two separate distros (each on its own partition), putting 'Windowsfx' on one, and 'Kali Linux' on the other, if possible...?

Wipe the partition table. Let Windows install itself from scratch. If you have an opportunity to choose how much disk space to assign to Windows then take it. Otherwise expect it to use the whole disk, at which point you'll need to shrink the Windows data partition to give yourself space for a Linux-based distribution. Now get your distribution and install it.

I would strongly suggest that you do not start with Kali. It's a very specific distribution designed for security professionals, and as such a lot of its services and subsystems are intentionally configured in a non-standard way. Try something more user friendly such as Mint.